# SQL, передача параметра в виде названия таблицы, столбцов

Tags: php, sql

Имеется код:

```
function selectDistinct($column){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM product");  
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$column);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($temp_param);

        $temp_array = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp_array[] = $temp_param;
        }
        return $temp_array;

    }
```

Хочу сделать функцию, для запроса уникальный значений таблицы в каждом столбце ($column).

Проблема в том что если я передам в функцию `$column = "brand"`, выдает ошибку, а если я сам в SQL запросе вместо `?` пропишу `brand`,то код отрабатывает отлично.
Вообще можно решить эту проблему?

**UPD**

Пока что придумал только напрямую в строку добавлять:

```
$string ='SELECT DISTINCT '.$column.' FROM '.$table;
```

Но думаю, что это не правильно

Comment: Подстановка непосредственно в текст - единственно возможное решение.

Comment: Может возможно процедурой, которая будет храниться в БД, передавая в не е параметры

Comment: В процедуре придется использовать так же динамическое формирование запроса в переменной в виде текста и выполнения этой переменной. Это ограничение не драйвера работы с БД, а самой базы данных. все имена должны быть вписаны сразу. Это связано с тем что выполнения запроса проходит 2 стадии: компиляции запроса, при котором уже разрешаются все имена, проверяется существование таблиц и колонок в них и фазы выполнения скомпилированного запроса, в которой происходит связывание параметров